# Best pattern to store a value used over 3 BUs

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dynamic-content

The use case is the following:

I have 3 urls which are used in many email content.
They are always the same. At the moment they are stored in every data extension that feeds each journey builder that use them. Every time we port from one environment to another one, we have to port the email content and change the dynamic content of the email that use that because the data source name is different.

I would like to use a more efficient way (in terms of time to deploy because the are many emails), what do u suggest to use?

1. store them in an ENT data extension
2. store them in a shared data extension
3. add if else ampscript inside the email content

or what else?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the URLs in a Shared Data Extension and use [Share Content](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_share_content.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) between the business units. If the URL is static, you can just store it in the Shared Content and negate the Shared Data Extension. Use the MID as the IF/THEN

Comment: thank u, I can retrieve via ampscript shared-DE without adding it the to attribute group, right?

Comment: @eeadev yes, you can. If the script returns a missing data extension use the ent. prefix. ("ent.DataExtenstionName",...